# After pressing qq, the status line says "recording". How do I get out of this mode?

Tags: macro

I accidentally pressed <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, and now the status line says `recording`.  What does that mean?  How do I get out of this "recording" mode?

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> doesn't work.

Comment: Can't you just read `:help recording`?

Comment: @romainl That's obvious in retrospect, but not to someone who is stuck.

Comment: This isn't strictly a "mode" in the Vim sense of the term, so I've edited out the [modes] tag.

Comment: @200_success `:help recording` isn't obvious, but `:help q` is and leads to the same place.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`q` is the command to begin the recording of a macro. By pressing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> you have told Vim to record a macro and store it in the register `q`. To stop Vim to record the macro, and thus to make the message `recording` disappear, you have to stop the recording by pressing <kbd>q</kbd> again. See [`:help recording`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#recording) for more details.